# Create Order Attribute (M1)

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, custom

I'm trying to create two Order Attributes in Magento 1.9.1.0.

I have the following in my custom module install script;

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute(
    'order',
    'ordersync_status_code',
    array(
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'backend_type' => 'varchar',
        'label' => 'Order Sync Status Code',
        'visible' => true,
        'required' => false,
        'user_defined' => false,
        'searchable' => true,
        'filterable' => true,
        'comparable' => true,
        'default' => ''
    )
);
$installer->addAttribute(
    'order',
    'ordersync_status_text',
    array(
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'backend_type' => 'varchar',
        'label' => 'Order Sync Status Text',
        'visible' => true,
        'required' => false,
        'user_defined' => false,
        'searchable' => true,
        'filterable' => true,
        'comparable' => true,
        'default'=> ''
    )
);
$installer->endSetup();
```

After install, I can see that two rows have been added to the sales_flat_order table for the above to attributes.

However, I can't see them in the eav_attribute table. Should I be able to see them here? I would have thought so. :/

The purpose of the fields;
I don't intend these to be editable when viewing or editing an order. They will simply hold some values that will be updated when orders are sent to a third party - so I simply need to present the data when viewing the sales order grid and the order itself.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment however I don't have enough reputation for that.

The attributes should show up in the **eav_attribute** table. It's possible that Magento already thinks that your module has already been installed and it is not running your installer. I would delete your module entry from the **core_resource** table to have your module run the installer again.

Comment: Thank you. Tried that a few times but doesn't seem to have worked. :( The module setup shows in the core_resource table and some other aspects of the custom module have installed fine (such as showing a column on the sales grid for the content of the new attribute).